# reading from text file and then sorting as per `word count in java

Tags: count, cpu-word

I have a requirement where from a text file need to find word count.and then sorting the words as per count.if count is same then sort the words with same count in alphabetical order.

I'v done most of it but last part is difficult for me.

after taking key=word value=count in a hashmap.and then using a treemap to sort the map as per count,I have the words stored in the map.now how to sort the words with same count in alphabetical order ?

Answer (score 0):

if you put some code it will be more easy to help.

to do the last part : **if count is same then sort the words with same count in alphabetical order.**

create a linkedlist that will contain all the words with the same count and then do a simple sort for the linkedlist.

```
LinkedList <String> sameWordsCount = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks,karim I'll add the code in sometime.but I am more concerned about the approach here.I''v edited my post above.